# Find $k$ such that $f(x,y) = k, 0<x<y<1$ is a probability joint density function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Find $k$ such that $f(x,y) = k, 0<x<y<1$ is a probability joint density function. ($f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise).

I'm having trouble with these combined integration limits. Is this correct?

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(x,y) dxdy = \int_{0}^{1} kydy = \frac{k}{2}$.

If $f$ is a joint density, then $\frac{k}{2} = 1 \iff k = 2$.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Is it also right that $f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{1} 2 dy = 2$ and $f_Y(y) = \int_{0}^{y} 2 dx = 2y$ ?

Comment: I find it weird because $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)dx$ is supposed to be $1$, but $\int_{0}^{y} 2 dx = 2y \neq 1$...

Comment: $$f_X(x) = \int_{x}^{1} 2 dy = 2(1-x)$$

Comment: Then to verify the property $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_X(x)dx = 1$ I must integrate from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: Yes again, as $x$ in $f_X(x)$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter, would you please take a look at this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688353/finding-the-probability-joint-distribution-which-density-is-fx-y-2-0xy1?noredirect=1#comment5552882_2688353

Comment: Is $f_Y(y) = 2y$ correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GnuSupporter said in the comments, it is indeed correct. The limits of the inner integral are $0$ and $y$ because $0<x<y$.